# Can't export IPA in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ipa

I just finished developing my iOs application using Phonegap on xCode 4.1 and i'm having trouble exporting my IPA for TestFlight. i have selected "iOs Device" at the left menu but when i click Product -> Archive i found this error: [BEROR]Code Sign error:

a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'Italianpizza.nearmilan' could not be found

What should i do? Please help me!
Best
Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO you have a provisioning profile installed in your computer ? if not , create it using [apple developer](http://developer.apple.com) and install it by using the organizer. You should also check that in your Bundle identifier you have the correct value for your application

Comment: Hi Tiziano, thanks for the reply. i *must* have an iOs Developer License to test app on testflight ?

Comment: Yes to test every app ypu are develoiping on a real device a provisioning profile is needed and you can obtain it only with a ios developer license